# Listview in a fragment OnClick New Activity - “Unfortunately, App has stopped”

Tags: android

I'm doing VR panorama view for tourist spots, I create a Tab Layout with listview,
In listview there are item is onclick to the new activity where the VR View appears but when I try to click the item, there a msg appears "Unfortunately, ATDRAG APP has stopped" when i try to create new activity it works, but when i use the VR View activity I received again that msg. What I'm supposed to do? That activity is Fragment. I will list down the codes here. Thank you in advance!

*LogCat*

```
02-08 11:23:02.243 10970-10970/? E/libprocessgroup: failed to make and chown /acct/uid_10060: Read-only file system
02-08 11:23:02.991 10970-10988/com.google.devrel.vrviewapp E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008cdf
02-08 11:23:03.030 10970-10988/com.google.devrel.vrviewapp E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008cdf
02-08 11:23:21.181 10970-10988/com.google.devrel.vrviewapp E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008cdf
02-08 11:23:21.341 10970-10988/com.google.devrel.vrviewapp E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008cdf
02-08 13:22:09.976 10970-10988/com.google.devrel.vrviewapp E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008cdf
02-08 13:22:10.178 10970-10988/com.google.devrel.vrviewapp E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008cdf
02-08 13:22:20.664 10970-11169/com.google.devrel.vrviewapp E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008cdf
02-08 13:22:20.709 10970-11169/com.google.devrel.vrviewapp E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008cdf
02-08 13:22:26.492 10970-11169/com.google.devrel.vrviewapp E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008cdf
02-08 13:22:26.753 10970-11169/com.google.devrel.vrviewapp E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008cdf
02-08 13:25:08.235 10970-11169/com.google.devrel.vrviewapp E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008cdf
02-08 13:25:08.544 10970-11169/com.google.devrel.vrviewapp E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008cdf
02-08 13:25:15.449 10970-11194/com.google.devrel.vrviewapp E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008cdf
02-08 13:25:15.463 10970-11194/com.google.devrel.vrviewapp E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008cdf
02-08 13:49:31.605 10970-11194/com.google.devrel.vrviewapp E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008cdf
02-08 13:49:31.947 10970-11194/com.google.devrel.vrviewapp E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008cdf
```

**MainActivity** Tab Layout

```
package com.google.devrel.vrviewapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        assert tabLayout != null;
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(R.string.welcome));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(R.string.venue));
        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

        final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        final PagerAdapter adapter = new FragmentStatePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()) {

            @Override
            public Fragment getItem(int position) {
                switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        return new WelcomeFragment();
                    case 1:
                        return new ttsd();
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return 2;
            }
        };
        assert viewPager != null;
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
    }

    public void refreshNow() {
        finish();
        overridePendingTransition(0,0);
        startActivity(getIntent());
        overridePendingTransition(0,0);
    }
}
```

**ttd** Listview Onclick item

```
package com.google.devrel.vrviewapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.AdapterView;

public class ttsd extends Fragment {


    public ttsd() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ttsd, container, false);
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        String[] awayStrings = {
                "Tubbataha Reef",
                "San Agustin Church",
                "Mayon Volcano",
                "Malapascua Island",
                "Puerto Galera",
                "Puerto Princesa Undergound River",
                "Donsol",
                "Banaue Rice Terraces",

        };

        ListView lv = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView2);

        ArrayAdapter<String> lva = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, awayStrings);
        lv.setAdapter(lva);

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                if(position==0) {
                    Intent myintent = new Intent(view.getContext(), toptourist2.class);
                    startActivityForResult(myintent, 0);
                }
            }
        });

        final SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_away);

        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(
                new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onRefresh() {
                        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).refreshNow();
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Refresh Layout working", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
        );

        return view;
    }
}
```

**toptourist1** the vr view

```
package com.google.devrel.vrviewapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import com.google.vr.sdk.widgets.pano.VrPanoramaView;


public class toptourist1 extends Fragment {

    private VrPanoramaView panoWidgetView;
    private ImageLoaderTask backgroundImageLoaderTask;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_toptourist1, container,false);
        panoWidgetView = (VrPanoramaView) v.findViewById(R.id.pano_view);
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        panoWidgetView.pauseRendering();
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        panoWidgetView.resumeRendering();
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        panoWidgetView.shutdown();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private synchronized void loadPanoImage() {
        ImageLoaderTask task = backgroundImageLoaderTask;
        if (task != null && !task.isCancelled()) {
            task.cancel(true);
        }

        VrPanoramaView.Options viewOptions = new VrPanoramaView.Options();
        viewOptions.inputType = VrPanoramaView.Options.TYPE_STEREO_OVER_UNDER;

        String panoImageName = "sample_converted.jpg";

        task = new ImageLoaderTask(panoWidgetView, viewOptions, panoImageName);
        task.execute(getActivity().getAssets());
        backgroundImageLoaderTask = task;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        loadPanoImage();
    }

}
```

Comment: that's not the error log. Please show your exception's log.

Comment: Any program will act like a user, like in Linux. Chown effectively says "this piece of data belongs to this user", but your program says it only has read as rights, not the write required to chown the folder to the program.

Comment: did your problem solved?

Answer (score 0):

this seems you want open panoImageName.jpg from device and you do not have permission for read SD card so add this line to your Manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

for api > 21 you must call this line

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(LoginActivity.this,
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
            1);
```

hope its helps

Comment: ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(LoginActivity.this,
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
            1); Where do i put this line?

Comment: in your onCreate of your MainActivity

Comment: My main activity is AppCompatActivity what should i do?